# Slow Message consumption in rabbitMq 3.6.5 . Why?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have 2 different environment .

Env1-
  **rabbitMq - 3.6.5** and   **erlang-  19.0.7** ,  **max message/sec - 250**

Env 2-
  **rabbitMq - 3.6.6**  and **erlang -  19.2**  ,  **max message/sec - 700**

What's new in 3.6.6 version so that its able to consume message quickly ...

Here is changelog link https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/tag/rabbitmq_v3_6_6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version 3.6.6 contains a couple of the features that improuve the performance:

1 - https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/973 it reduces the GC calls (under certain condition) improving the performance.

2 - https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/949 that increase the `credit_flow` value, this delay the `flow` status control so you have a better performance